# How to Make a Nice Block of Commenting in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2010, coding-style, comments

I just switched back to c++ after leaving it for awhile and I can't seem to remember how to make nice function/class comment boxes in VS. What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
/**   
 * Convenience struct: coord
 * -------------------------
 * Simple C++ struct (which is like a class, except there are
 * no methods and everything is public) that bundles two related
 * pieces of data together.
 */

struct coord {
    int row;
    int col;
    };
```

I don't, however, want to have to format out the nice starring and alignment every time I want to write a new comment. I feel like I used to be able to just type '/**' and then hit return and it would automatically make a comment section for me where every time I hit return a new star would appear aligned with the others. Is there a way to activate this in VS 2010?

Comment: Actually, I miss this all the time from vim, so I'm gonna write up an extension to try to approximate that behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Assist is the tool you require. If you can move away from MSVC IDE, can try Eclipse also.

Comment: I'm not sure if the username is ironic to coincide with the advice given.

Comment: I never said it sucks. It is sort of dreary without Visual Assist. And choosing an IDE doesn't make a coder, I presume :)

Comment: See the "Auto-extend multi-line comments" option on the Advanced | Corrections page of the VA Options dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Try [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) for a starting point. It is fairly configurable and gives you a documentaion template with one hotkey sequence.

[Edit]

I mistook this for a C# question. As Billy pointed out, GhostDoc is not a good solution for C++ in VS.

Try this SO question about ["GhostDoc for C++?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532779/is-there-anything-like-ghostdoc-for-c) for some other ideas.

Comment: GhostDoc does not support C++.

Comment: Argh, my mistake Billy. I saw VS2010 and skimmed over the "C++" in the question. I assumed C# incorrectly. Carry on ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to record a nice macro to do this, then bind it to an unused button/shortcut key combo and your set, else its pretty trivial to code a simple VS plugin to do this with some extra embelishments