# How to quickly add XML comments to C++ code in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, xml, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

In C# i just type "///" and it creates nice comment block with information partially there.

Is there any way to do the same for C++ code?
Maybe plugin?

This is just example

```
   /// <summary>
   /// Description for SomeMethod.</summary>
   /// <param name="s"> Parameter description for s goes here</param>
   /// <seealso cref="String">
   /// You can use the cref attribute on any tag to reference a type or member 
   /// and the compiler will check that the reference exists. </seealso>
   public void SomeMethod(string s)
   {
   }
```

Comment: Not sure about vs2013 but code::blocks has a button on the toolbar to generate a block comment, none of the details are filled in but tags like \brief, \return and \param are automatically created

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059773/generate-xml-documentation-comments-for-in-visual-studio-2010-c

Answer (score 0):

Try [Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/). More info in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532779/is-there-anything-like-ghostdoc-for-c) question.

Comment: I"m using it. But it doesn't have that feature.